Nest "For Each" loops in Geometry Nodes
I want to make a simple test of connecting a line to and from each point in an icosphere.
I have it so that we loop through each point, get the location, feed that into another loop and use that location along with the location of every other point to create lines. We ignore this creation if the index of the two points are the same.
Here is my setup.

However, this simply gives the correct number of lines with the start and end points as -1 and 0.

Am I missing something or this a limitation with the nodes?

Keep in mind Repeat and For Each zones are slow. You can connect all points by "quadratically exploding" geometry, by instancing it onto itself and using that to create connecting edges.

Can you explain that further? What does quadratically exploding mean? Each point needs an icospheres worth of points... I tried playing around with how I might achieve it with instancing but couldn't solve it.

Here's 3 examples: sorting, before "Sort" node existed, more refined: gravity (all-to-all relation) and maybe the simplest example in the bunch: How to find the 2 vertices that are furthest apart?

A bit unintuitive. But apparently you are supposed to sample at index 0 as each element fed into the for each loop is singular and thus has an index of 0.


